# How to add dedications to journal article

Tags: titles

I would like to add

```
"in loving memory of J. Smith"
```

between title and list of authors in a *journal article* (not thesis) with `siamonline` class. I am aware of the `\dedicatory` command that comes with some AMS classes. But I cannot find a similar command for SIAM classes.

Answer (score 2):

Write the title as

```
\title{%
    An Example Article\thanks{Submitted to the editors DATE.    
    \funding{This work was funded by the Fog Research Institute under contract no.~FRI-454.}} \\[2ex]       
{\normalfont \normalsize \sffamily  \textcolor{black}{``in loving memory of J. Smith''}}    
}
```

[image: a]

Used with `\documentclass{siamonline171218}`